# Tag synonym request for symlink and softlink

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Could you add [softlink](/questions/tagged/softlink) to [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink)?

<del>Even if symlink is more often used I think softlink is the official term.</del>
Now vice vesa. In Mention of Kevin Vermeer posting I exchanged the two tags. I didn't checked which term is more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symlink, short for symbolic link, is the official terminology according to the POSIX specification:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html

> symlink - make a symbolic link to a file

I'd never heard of a softlink until today.  It seems to be the logical opposite of a hard link (which would be 'soft link', which ought to result in the tag [soft-link](/questions/tagged/soft-link), right?), but the official name on Linux, Mac, and Windows for these files is symlink.

I note that [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) does mention soft links:

> In computing, a symbolic link (also symlink or soft link)

but it only does this in the introduction, in the reference to the Amiga OS ([where they are called soft links](http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~mszyprow/programy/asfs/asfs.txt)), and in a reference to what I can only assume is a misguided Linux tutorial.

Additionally, there are 338 questions tagged [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink), and 10 questions tagged [softlink](/questions/tagged/softlink).  There is already a synonym mapping [symbolic-link](/questions/tagged/symbolic-link) to [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink).  I could support mapping [softlink](/questions/tagged/softlink) to [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink), but not the other direction.

Comment: I personally know symink only in a linux context, but you are right that must have a sense that symlink is more often used than softlink. I will exchange the two tags.